# Phlacon: Getting multidimensional data from POST

Tags: multidimensional-array, phalcon

If I want to get `$_POST['username']` I write `$this->request->getPost('username');`. But how I must write to get `$_POST['profile']['username']`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->request->getPost('profile')['username'];
```

To be certain to avoid invalid key errors:

```
$profile = $this->request->getPost('profile');
$username = isset($profile['username']) ? $profile['username'] : null;
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address a multidimensional array.

Comment: The first part shows how to get `$_POST['profile']['username']`, which is a multidimensional array by definition. The second part shows how to avoid errors in situations when you receive unexpected input, e.g., from a modified form which doesn't provide the expected POST data. Exactly what's being asked in the question + a useful tip. Do you see it differently?

Comment: My apologies, and maybe it's the way the question was worded, but I thought they were asking how to get their POST to contain a multidimensional array. They never accepted your answer so I thought the answer needed a little more to it. But they only have 4 rep, so maybe they never will accept an answer. >.<

Answer (score -1):

It's important to setup your form properly. You don't use `[ ]` around 'profile.' The php side won't know what to do with it if you post `[profile][username]`. It has to be `profile[username]`

```
<input type="text" name="profile[username]" value="jsmith" />
<input type="text" name="profile[password]" value="******" />
```

```php
<?php

    $profile = $this->request->getPost('profile');
    echo $profile['username'];

?>
```

Output: "jsmith"

For multidimensional you would add a key of your own to base it on.

```html
<input type="text" name="profile[first][username]" value="jsmith" />
<input type="text" name="profile[first][password]" value="******" />
```

```php
<?php

    $profile = $this->request->getPost('profile');
    echo $profile['first']['username'];

?>
```

Output: "jsmith"

Comment: A down vote with no comment? This works, so why the down vote?

Answer (score -2):

This is no way. Because, I use `$this->request->getPost('useremail', 'email')` for checking post data.

Comment: You can get data and filter them later or just bind with form that has proper validation.